# OAuth2 vs SAML vs Openid

Tags: web-services, oauth, oauth-2.0, saml

I am developing an application mobile and wanted to know the safest way to access this data on the web?

OAuth2 vs SAML vs Openid vs ?

I'm using jax rs in webservice and in mobile android and swift. How do large applications develop this security?

Comment: Welcome to the site.You did not give a examle of your usecase. Problem is, those protocols do not solve the same thing - oauth2 gives you authorization but not authentication (technically it is possible to piggyback it to some degree, but it is not there by design); SAML gives you federated identity which (as a side effect) gives you also SSO authentication; openid is an extension to oauth and gives you authentication+authorization. You should extend your question because asking which of the protocols is "the best" without knowing your usecase makes the question virtually unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

There are three protocols you can use:

- WS-Federation
- SAML 2.0
- OpenID Connect / OAuth

These connect to an Identity provider e.g. ADFS, Azure AD, Auth0, identityserver4, Okta etc.

For mobile, OpenID Connect is the best fit as it is modelled on REST and allows SPA.

There a samples for most of these e.g. [Azure AD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-swift-native-v2), [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ios-swift/00-login).